How to prevent Win 11 pending updates from throttling system
On both my local PCs I've noticed a pattern where every time a new Win 11 update is pushed and automatically downloaded to wait for install it starts throttling my system performance until I actually restart to finish the install. I'll get spikes of random stuttering even on low draw apps or games with 50%+ system resources and on things never stutter typically, and go back to normal following the update. This doesn't seem to be just a typical restart issue, because pretty much every time I've actually restarted my PCs in the last couple years has been Windows Update related and I don't really run into issues otherwise. As they tend to push Windows updates relatively frequently, this has grown to critically annoying.
Now, I'm aware the simple fix is to just disable Windows Update entirely, but I don't actually want to never get an update as they can definitely be beneficial and if I disabled it I'm sure I would never think to check for updates again and would run into issues down the road as my versioning gets deprecated. My question is if anyone else has run into this before (honestly it kind of sounds like a Windows "feature" to encourage you to restart for new updates as soon as possible) and if the system limitation is something I can disable independently or a defect of some other optional component that can be disabled without going nuclear and maybe having to write my own manager for the update system.

I can safely say what you describe absolutely isn’t a feature.

With Windows 11 Pro, you can use change Windows Update policy to "Notify to download and auto install". This requires using the Local Group Policy Editor. If you are using Windows 11 Home, then you may want to post as question on how to enable this editor.
The steps for changing the Windows Update policy are given below.

Open the Run application and enter gpedit.msc.

Select , Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > All Settings > Configure Automatic Updates, as shown below.


Under Configure Automatic Updates, select "policy setting" to open the popup window shown below.


Select the "Enabled" buttion, then select "2 - Notify to download and auto install" under Options, as shown below.


Select the OK button, then close the editor.


When updates are available for download, you will get the notification shown below.

